# Embed semicolon in args[] variable in launch.json

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm running into a strange issue when debugging a PowerShell script in VS Code. I am trying to initialize my arguments array with variables that I need to set prior to running the script. My `launch.json` contains:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "PowerShell",
        "type": "PowerShell",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "args": ["wgoulet","f0tobug\u003b","c:\\usercode\\entries.txt"],
        "cwd": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "name": "PowerShell x86",
        "type": "PowerShell x86",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my debug session, when I examine the contents of the `$args` array, I see that the argument after the ';' character is ignored, as well as the semicolon itself.

In other words, when I look at the `$args` argument in PowerShell, I see the following:

```
$args[0]="wgoulet"
$args[1]="f0tobug"
```

What I expect to see is

```
$args[0]="wgoulet"
$args[1]="f0tobug;"
$args[2]="c:\\usercode\\entries.txt"
```

If I modify the `'f0tobug;'` parameter so that it doesn't contain a ';', the arguments array is populated correctly. I even tried encoding the ';' as Unicode with `\u003b`, but I got the same result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752071/how-do-i-add-command-line-arguments-in-visual-studio-code-with-semicolons-in-the/60876495#60876495 this may have been fixed since.